# What is this large drag-grey piece? I see it being sold with 9v train tracks, and it is about the same size

Tags: trains

[image]

What is this piece?  I see it being sold with 9v train tracks

Comment: Great question! Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 4):

That's part [42936 Track System, Straight Track 16 x 8 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42936).

[image: part photo]

It was used in the Racers track system and was found in sets in the early 2000s such as [4588 Off-Road Race Track](https://brickset.com/sets/4588-1/Off-Road-Race-Track):

[image: 4588 instruction track image]

It really has nothing to do with 9V train track, but sellers don't always understand the details of different track systems and simply sell elements that look like track together.